# What is a regex for calculating two fields?

Tags: ruby, regex, html-parsing

I have HTML like:

```
<div id="c_pcnb" style="height:11px;width:4px;visibility:hidden;position:absolute;">
```

and I want to sum `4px` and `11px`, but I don't know how. I just get these values, but I didn't work with groups and two values. How do I do this?

```
@sizes = (/height:([\d]+)px;width:([\d]+)px;visibility:hidden;position:absolute;/.match body_text)
```

I must sum height + width.

When I try `@sizes[1] + @sizes[2]` I get errors. What did I do wrong?

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/ruby for examples of how to properly parse HTML with Ruby modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: @AndyLester with Arup's answer, how to be if 11px;width:4px are dynamic, not const

Comment: This is an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968); You want an answer for using regular expressions to parse HTML, when you should really be asking how do you parse HTML to reliably extract data from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
'<div id=\"c_pcnb\" style=\"height:11px;width:4px;visibility:hidden;position:absolute;\">' \
     .scan(/\d+/) \
     .inject{|s,n| Integer(s) + Integer(n)}   #returns 15
```

Example 2:

```
'<div style=\"height:221px;width:47px;\">' \
   .scan(/\d+/).inject{|s,n| Integer(s) + Integer(n)} #=>268
```

It simply picks up all the `(\d+)`, converts to `Integer` and provides the `Sum`:

```
css='<div id=\"c_pcnb\" style=\"height:11px;width:4px;visibility:hidden;position:absolute;\">' 
css.scan(/\d+/).inject{|s,n| Integer(s) + Integer(n)} #=> 15
```

Comment: also 11px;width:4px are dynamic, not const

Comment: I have provided explanation of what it does. It does not treat values as constant. Just picks up all Integers. The solution is a single line construct. Note the `\`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do as below :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc= Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-eotl
<div id="c_pcnb" style="height:11px;width:4px;visibility:hidden;position:absolute;">
eotl

hsh = Hash[*doc.at_css('#c_pcnb')['style'].split(/[:;]/)]
# => {"height"=>"11px",
#     "width"=>"4px",
#     "visibility"=>"hidden",
#     "position"=>"absolute"}
(hsh["height"].to_i + hsh["width"].to_i).to_s + 'px'
# => "15px"
```

Comment: Can anyone one tell me why the this solution is being given down-voted. HTML is not good for regex. Why this standard one is being given down-votes..?

Comment: maybe becouse you didn't read question? there is no: ot how is it more good and right to do? What is a regex for calculating two fields   but now what is better, or ever nokogiri! Question was about regex, i'm new, and wanna learn first all about regex

Comment: but also, it didn't work, when i have height:11px;width:4px;visibility:hidden;position:absolute;  all is ok, but when height:10px;width:15px;visibility:hidden;position:absolute; etc it doesn't see it!

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris You are going to a wrong track.. Now it is your choice,of-course.. But don't think that down votes for that reasons,there are some hidden reasons,that only down voters know and god knows.. Myself don't. The answer is not that much bad,that it is consuming 3 down votes..

Comment: Arup, all is ok, i learn something new about nokogiri, i will use this in future, but now what now) i now that your's solution is better...